# How to re-use a state store in an aggregate and a preprocessor?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have messages that I'd like to aggregate into a state, but I'd also
like to use that state in a preprocess step that might update other
states as well. An example might be to see if this message changes
some part of the state, and if so, update a topic that tracks that
specific part of the state, as well as the state itself.

The best way I could imagine to do this was to use a Transformer that
had access to the state store, but do so before aggregating the state,
so that I could see what the value of the state is before it's
updated.  (The Transformer in question will just return the original
message after possibly having updated the extra state.)

However, I get into a chicken-and-egg problem there:

1. If I add the `Materialized` with `aggregate()` as below, I get a
   topology error indicating that the state store I'm trying to access
   hasn't been added to the topology yet.

   ```
   KStream<String, Message> stream = streamsBuilder.stream(config.getDefaultSourceTopicName(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new MessageSerde()));
         streamBuilder
             .transformValues(
                 new MessagePreprocessorSupplier(
                     "state_store_topic_name"
                 ),
                 "state_store_topic_name"
             )
             .groupByKey()
             .aggregate(
                 () -> null,
                 new MyAggregator(),
                 Materialized.as("state_store_topic_name")
             );
   ```

   This raises:

   ```
   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore state_store_topic_name is not added yet.
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.connectProcessorAndStateStore(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:716)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.connectProcessorAndStateStores(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:615)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl.transformValues(KStreamImpl.java:546)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl.transformValues(KStreamImpl.java:538)
   at myapp.stream_processor.KafkaApplication.configureTopology(KafkaApplication.java:48)
   ```
2. If I try to create the state store first, then I can add it to the
   transformer, but I get an error when I call `.aggregate()`,
   indicating that it can't add the state store at that point, because
   we already added it earlier.

   ```
   Materialized<String, MyState, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> myStateStoreProvider =
       Materialized.<String, Thermostat, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("state_store_topic_name")
           .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
           .withValueSerde(myStateSerde);
   /* really don't think we should need this, but if I don't, the .transformValues
      says it wasn't added to the topology... */
   streamsBuilder.table("state_store_topic_name", myStateStoreProvider);

   KStream<String, Message> stream = streamsBuilder.stream(config.getDefaultSourceTopicName(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new MessageSerde()));
         streamBuilder
             .transformValues(
                 new MessagePreprocessorSupplier(
                     "state_store_topic_name"
                 ),
                 "state_store_topic_name"
             )
             .groupByKey()
             .aggregate(
                 () -> null,
                 new MyAggregator(),
                 myStateStoreProvider
             );
   ```

   This raises:

   ```
   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore state_store_topic_name is already added.
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.addStateStore(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:523)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.GroupedStreamAggregateBuilder.build(GroupedStreamAggregateBuilder.java:71)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KGroupedStreamImpl.doAggregate(KGroupedStreamImpl.java:488)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KGroupedStreamImpl.aggregateMaterialized(KGroupedStreamImpl.java:175)
   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KGroupedStreamImpl.aggregate(KGroupedStreamImpl.java:167)
   at myapp.stream_processor.KafkaApplication.configureTopology(KafkaApplication.java:48)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It might work if you fall back to Processor API for connecting the store to the transformer:

- you add the transformer without adding a state (because it does not exist yet)
- you add your aggregation regularly such that the state is created
- after you called `builder.build()`, you call `Topology#connectProcessorAndStateStore()`

  - you need to pass in the name of the transformer and the store
  - you can retrieve the name of the transformer via `Topology#describe()`

I have not tried this out though...

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked for me! It's a bit brittle though as it relies on some naming conventions used in naming topology nodes in DSL. I wonder if the confluence guys are considering allowing naming DSL expression parts so we can reference them when mixing with processor API.

Comment: Looks like this feature is coming! https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-307%3A+Allow+to+define+custom+processor+names+with+KStreams+DSL